# Replacing something in an expression

Tags: replacement

I have an expression as follows:

```
  expr = K*ComplexExpand[Abs[f]^4] + 
  P*D[(ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f]] // TrigToExp), x]
```

where f is a function with two variables, such as `f=g[x,t]`.

I want to substitute the followings into `expr`

```
conjug = ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f]] // TrigToExp;
abs = ComplexExpand@Abs[f];
```

As a result, I want to get the following result.

```
K*abs^4 + P*D[conjug, x]
```

The following does not work or when I also use `Unevaluated` , it does not work.

```
expr /. {ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f]] -> conjug, 
  ComplexExpand@Abs[f] -> abs}
```

Comment: Note `K` is a system symbol. It is not `Protected` but it is used by system functions sometimes, such as `D[]`. And when it is used, it might just mess up your code. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395

Comment: Note `D[conjug, x]` evaluates to zero, which you probably don't want. Maybe you should aim for `D[conjug[x, t], x]` instead?

Comment: This works: `ClearAll[conjug, abs];
f = g[x, t];
expr = K*ComplexExpand[Abs[f]^4] + 
   P*D[(ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f]] // TrigToExp), x];
expr /. {D[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f]] -> conjug[x, t], x], 
  ComplexExpand@Abs[f] -> abs}` -- BUT...You know, without the actual `f` I'm not sure this can be done with replacement. Algebraic transformations are difficult to achieve with replacement except in simple cases. The presence of `D[.., x]` makes this case not simple, *prima facie*. Autosimplification can trouble. Sometimes special functions cause trouble, too. And dependencies.